# Online books or articles on Ampere model

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, resource-recommendations, classical-electrodynamics, magnetic-moment

I am interested in studying Ampere model of force between magnets. Can anybody introduce me to some online books or articles on this subject. Searched the net a lot but can't find any except wikipedia. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: As the Gilbert model is largely of historical interest, this question might be better-suited to [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange.](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I actually need Ampere model. Gilbert model isn't necessary.